# Insufficient privileges error when trying to fetch signed in user's group membership using Azure AD Graph API

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I need to be able to get the signed in user's group membership so that I can verify whether he is part of a specific group. However **I am getting "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." exception using the Azure AD graph API client library.**

I am a co-admin of a subscription and I have created a new Azure AD application to authenticate against the default directory and configured the "Permission to Other application" section as in the below screenshot.

[Azure AD Application Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RmcJh.png)

I am able to fetch the signed in user details, but when I try to call MemberOf function, then I get the above exception. Please let me know what I am missing here. Thanks in advance!

```
string objectId = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier").Value; // object id of the signed in user

ActiveDirectoryClient client = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClient(); 

IUser user = await client.Users.GetByObjectId(objectId).ExecuteAsync();
var userFetcher = (IUserFetcher)user; // able to fetch the signed in user

IPagedCollection<IDirectoryObject> pagedCollection = await userFetcher.MemberOf.ExecuteAsync(); // getting error here - "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I had selected the permissions outside the 'personal scope' (Access the directory as the signed in user, Read directory data).

**Hence, it needed consent from the service administrator of the subscription associated to the directory. Once the admin logs into the app and approves the consent screen, the code should stop giving insufficient privileges exception.**

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14205066)

Comment: @Deepak - The posted answer resolved the problem for me and is not meant to be additional info. The issue was due to Admin consent not provided for the Azure AD application from the directory admin. Can you guide me on what can be improved here?