# Get-PnPUnifiedGroup : Code: Authorization_RequestDenied

Tags: azure, graph, office365

How do I get a unified group from graph using this command

```
$group = Get-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity $sitetitle
```

Then I get this error:

> Get-PnPUnifiedGroup : Code: Authorization_RequestDenied

Trying to connect with tenant user:

```
## know that this is not going to work
Connect-PnPOnline "https://$tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -Credentia $cred
```

and using AADDomain with all graph permission

```
Connect-PnPOnline -AppId $appid -AppSecret $appsecret -AADDomain "$tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
```

also trid with certificate ..

```
Connect-PnPOnline -CertificatePath .\xxxxxcertkeyname.pfx -Tenant 'xxxxxxxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com' -ClientId 'xxxxxxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx-xxxxxx' -Url 'https://xxxxxxxx-admin.sharepoint.com'
```

But can't get to work

Comment: Please check if the answer in this post works for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002684/authorization-requestdenied-when-trying-to-get-groups-from-azure-active-director

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You schould connect with a specific scope

```
Connect-PnPOnline "https://$tenant-admin.sharepoint.com" -Scope "Group.Read.All" -Credentia $cred
```

`-Scope "Group.Read.All"` or `-Scope "Group.ReadWrite.All", "Directory.ReadWrite.All"` if you are planning to change any group

Available permissions for graph api
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/blob/master/concepts/permissions_reference.md