# issue getting authorization code for Request token from Azure Active Directory

Tags: java, rest

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-oauth-code#oauth-20-authorization-flow

I used the above link

**Response**

We can't sign you in
Your browser is currently set to block cookies. You need to allow cookies to use this service.
Cookies are small text files stored on your computer that tell us when you're signed in. To learn how to allow cookies, check the online help in your web browser.

Comment: Use this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41002684/authorization-requestdenied-when-trying-to-get-groups-from-azure-active-director

Comment: if you are not getting data using a token then you just change the  resource https://graph.microsoft.com